# storing image in Oracle database Table

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I have to store image in Oracle Database Table.For this I am reading the uploaded file as byte of array

```
    string fileName = Server.MapPath("files") + @"/columnsdd.txt";
    Stream str = Request.Files[0].InputStream;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[str.Length];
    str.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

and then I an passing this byte of array (buffer) to a stored procedure.

```
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = (new OracleConnection(connec));
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "InsetImag";
    OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter();
    param1.ParameterName = "image";
    param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    param1.Value = buffer;
    param1.OracleType = OracleType.Blob;
```

The stored procedure used above is

```
create or replace procedure InsetImag(image in Blob,imageNAME in  Varchar)
is
Begin
 insert into Images values(image,'xyz.jpg');
ENd;
```

The defnition for table Images

```
Column | DataType
 Image | Blob
 ImageName | Varchar2(20)
```

But , on trying to insert image into the Db i am getting

```
  ora-01460:unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested
```

ABove code works fine if i uplad a PDF file but it fails for jpg and doc files.
Any idea why?

Comment: hope this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256558/17447

Comment: see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;322796 for answer